# select if is null

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, inner-join

I need to make the inner join of two tables, however, wanted to know how can I resolve this situation:

If the field in the second table is NULL he do inner join with another field.

Can you give me an example?

Thanks

Comment: more information please - difficult to say what to do with the NULL without know what you want to achieve?

Comment: try using coalesce:

`select TableA.Col1, TableB.Col2
From TableA
INNER JOIN TableB on TableA.JoinColumn=coalesce(TableB.JoinCoumn1, TableB.JoinColum2, TableB.JoinColumn3......and so on)`

That will consider TableB.JoinColumn1, then 2, then 3, halting at the first non-null column value.

Comment: @whytheq I think I explained well! and cant understanda the downvotes

Comment: @StephenByrne I used an inner join with the "case when ..." because coalesce is not working for me.

Comment: @sh0rt6r we could do with seeing what the initial data looks like; we could also do with see an example of the result set you are trying to achieve

Comment: @sh0rt6r looks at this question: [**STACK OVERFLOW**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-sql-server) ; it is very clear what they are starting with and what they are trying to achieve. If you make you question more clear then the down-votes will probably disappear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

depends what you are trying to achieve...

```
CREATE TABLE #X 
(
[Id] INT,
[Name] VARCHAR(100)
)
INSERT INTO #X VALUES
(1,'michaeljackson'),
(2,'jim'),
(3,'jill'),
(4,'j')

CREATE TABLE #Y 
(
[Id] INT,
[AlternateId] INT,
[Score] INT
)
INSERT INTO #Y VALUES
(1,1,10),
(2,2,20),
(3,3,30),
(4,4,40),
(NULL,2,50)

--will join all of the records in #x to the null record
SELECT *
FROM   #X x
       INNER JOIN #Y y
       ON 
       x.Id = COALESCE(y.Id,x.Id)

--will join just to the ID = 4 record
SELECT *
FROM   #X x
       INNER JOIN #Y y
       ON 
       x.Id = COALESCE(y.Id,4)


--redirect and let join use alternative field
SELECT *
FROM   #X x
       INNER JOIN #Y y
       ON 
       x.Id = COALESCE(y.Id,y.AlternateId)

--maybe you want to actually do a FULL OUTER JOIN!
SELECT  *
FROM    #X x
    FULL OUTER JOIN #Y y
    ON 
    x.Id = y.Id
```

Comment: I used an inner join with the "case when ..." because coalesce is not working for me.

Comment: I actually created a further question to explore differences between `CASE/COALESCE` [**Stackoverflow question here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15523000/coalesce-or-case-more-efficient-and-or-standard)

Answer (score 1):

Easiest is probalby to consider the second table as two disjoint tables like this:

```
select *
from a
join (
    select NewKey = key1, * from b where b.key1 is null
  union all
    select NewKey = key2, * from b where b.key1 is not null
) b on b.NewKey = a.key
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. not tested because it could solve with using CASE WHEN

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following should work adequately.

```
SELECT *
  FROM tblA a
    INNER JOIN tblB b ON (b.Col1 IS NOT NULL AND b.Col1 = a.Col1) OR (b.Col1 IS NULL AND b.Col2 = a.Col2)
```

If b.Col1 is not NULL then it joins on Col1, otherwise if it is NULL then it joins on Col2.

Comment: thanks for the reply. not tested because it could solve with using CASE WHEN

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    select * from a 
    inner join b on 
    (case when b.columntojoin is null then b.alternatecolumn else b.columntojoin end) 
    = a.columntojoin
```