# COALESCE or CASE more efficient and/or standard

Tags: standards, sql

In terms of x compared to y.

- Does x comply with sql standards better? [apologies if subjective]
- Is x more efficient than y?
- Or are these scripts completely different and to be used in different contexts?

x

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM   a 
           INNER JOIN b ON
           COALESCE(b.columntojoin, b.alternatecolumn) = a.columntojoin
```

y

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM   a 
           INNER JOIN b ON
           (case when b.columntojoin is null then b.alternatecolumn else b.columntojoin end) = a.columntojoin
```

Comment: Perhaps subjective on my part, but it seems contradictory to be concerned about which is "more standard" while you have a fluid database design where the join column changes based on whether a column contains a null value. That join raises red flags for me. On its face, it is fragile design.

Comment: @Tim - more constructive if you add this as an answer - fully explaining your "red flags" and "fragile design" concerns ....I understand `null` should be avoided in `a` and `b`: but that is a whole different topic!

Comment: If I would make it an answer, it would be downvoted, and I would be reprimanded that it should have been a comment :-)

Comment: To explain: your table B has two columns that are foreign keys pointing back at a column in table A. It is acceptable to have a column allow NULL values when the column is in a child table in a foreign key relationship. To have two such columns in the table, both allowing nulls, pointing back at the same column in the same parent table, suggests a denormalization has occurred, and that IS non-standard.

Comment: @Tim thanks for the explanation; it's not my db - I'm just after the standard way of interrogating it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`COALESCE` is essentially a shorthanded `CASE` statement.

Both are **exactly** the same.

There is also `ISNULL` in SQL Server (differs in other DBMSs), but that's actually a non-standard feature and is actually more limited that `COALESCE`.

Comment: I think COALESCE also makes for more readable code, and is more portable IIRC.

Comment: Actually, isnull is has different names in different dbs.  In oracle it's nvl.  In redbrick, it's ifnull.  That's probably what you meant by non-standard.

Comment: @DanBracuk Yeah that's what I meant, I elaborated to make it clear.

Comment: `ISNULL` is not standard so I've not used it

Answer (score 2):

In this case I would use `COALESCE` ( which provides more levels than `ISNULL`) rather than the `CASE` stement.

The `CASE` statement seems a bit bulky here, seeing as you are only checking for `NULL`s anyway.