# Django: Order by evaluation of whether or not a date is empty

Tags: python, django

In Django, is it possible to order by whether or not a field is None, instead of the value of the field itself?

I know I can send the QuerySet to python `sorted()` but I want to keep it as a QuerySet for subsequent filtering. So, I'd prefer to order in the QuerySet itself.

For example, I have a termination_date field and I want to first sort the ones without a termination_date, then I want to order by a different field, like last_name, first_name.

Is this possible or am I stuck using `sorted()` and then having to do an entire new Query with the included ids and run `sorted()` on the new QuerySet? I can do this, but would prefer not to waste the overhead and use the beauty of QuerySets that they don't run until evaluated.

Translation, how can I get this SQL from Django assuming my app is `employee`, my model is `Employee` and it has three fields 'first_name (varchar)', 'last_name (varchar)', and 'termination_date (date)':

```
SELECT
    "employee_employee"."last_name",
    "employee_employee"."first_name",
    "employee_employee"."termination_date"

FROM "employee_employee"

ORDER BY
    "employee_employee"."termination_date" IS NOT NULL,
    "employee_employee"."last_name",
    "employee_employee"."first_name"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to order by [query expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/expressions/), like this:

```
from django.db.models import IntegerField, Case, Value, When

MyModel.objects.all().order_by(
    Case(
        When(some_field=None, then=Value(1)),
        default=Value(0),
        output_field=IntegerField(),
    ).asc(),
    'some_other_field'
)
```

I cannot test here so it might require a bit a fiddling around, but this should put rows that have a NULL `some_field` after those that have a `some_field`. And each set of rows should be sorted by `some_other_field`.

Granted, the CASE/WHEN is be a bit more cumbersome that what you put in your question, but I don't know how to get Django ORM to output that. Maybe someone else will have a better answer.

Comment: Amazing, I have been working with Django for years and have never come across the Case class. Thanks so much, worked perfectly!

Comment: @Furbeenator> it is a fairly recent addition. I think Django 1.7, perhaps even 1.8. The djangoproject team is trying to kill the `.extra()` method by making Django ORM much more expressive with combinable query expressions. Better encapsulation and portability.

Comment: That makes sense, I have to admit, I've been maintaining Django since 1.3 and haven't looked at the latest two release notes for all that has been updated. Shame on me... :-/

Answer (score 2):

Spectras' answer works fine, but it only orders your records by 'null or not'. There is a shorter way that allows you to put empty dates wherever you want them in your date ordering - **`Coalesce`**:

```
from django.db.models import Value
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

wayback = datetime(year=1, month=1, day=1)  # or whatever date you want
MyModel.objects
       .annotate(null_date=Coalesce('date_field', Value(wayback)))
       .order_by('null_date')
```

This will essentially sort by the field `'date_field'` with all records with `date_field == None` will be in the order as if they had the date `wayback`. This works perfectly with PostgreSQL, but might need some raw sql casting in MySQL as described in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/database-functions/#coalesce).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, @schwobaseggl! I hadn't heard of `Coalesce` before either. It must also be a relatively new addition. Do you know if there is a resource advantage to either `Coalesce` or using the `Case` statement mentioned by @spectras?

Comment: It has been added in 1.8. It appears, the two are very similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15523000/coalesce-or-case-more-efficient-and-or-standard. You can check the generated SQL with `str(queryset.query)`, they don't differ much. Coalesce is basically a shortcut.